# where to put utility code used by a controller and a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Our app has "notifications" which you view through your inbox on the site, and can also get email to tell you about them.  When you receive a notification, it contains a link to reply to the message in question. That might mean sending a PM back to the sender of the original message, or might mean leaving a comment on a post.

This is the code to figure out what reply link to use:

```
if @notification.post
  # comment on the post in question
  @reply_link = new_comment_path(:post_id => @notification.post.id)
else
  # by default, reply link sends a PM in return
  @reply_link = new_notification_path(
    :recipient_id => @notification.sender.id,
    :subject => @notification.subject =~ /^Re: / ?
      @notification.subject :
      "Re: " + @notification.subject
  ) 
end
```

I took that from our controller code, btw: `app/controllers/notifications_controller.rb`

Now we want to include the same reply link in our email notifications, which means we need to do the same sort of reply link generation in `app/mailers/notifier.rb`

I don't want to repeat myself, so I would rather create a `reply_link` method and put it somewhere where both the controller and the mailer can access it.

My first thought was to put it in the model, so that we could have `Notification.reply_link`.  That'd be nice, but it doesn't work because we need `new_comment_path` and `new_notification_path` which aren't available in the model.

My second thought was to use a helper, but a) everyone seems to think that helpers suck, and b) we couldn't get it to work anyway.

So, where should I be putting this handy `reply_link` method, so that it will be accessible to both the controller and the mailer, and in keeping with good coding practices?

Answer (score 2):

Extract it to a module and 'mix it in' to access it in both places you need it.

You can put the module anywhere you like: the lib folder has been a historically popular place, or create a 'modules' folder in your app directory.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `/app/helpers` or `/lib`

I generally tend to put methods accessed from controllers in helpers